# corrupted unsorted chunks, glibc error?

Tags: c, free, glibc

corrupted unsorted chunks, what this means and how could i solve it ?
this happened from C program, under ubuntu with gcc, and to before i free it i print it,

```
printf("temp [%s]\n",temp);
free(temp); // << and here all the trouble become
```

.

```
*** glibc detected *** ./pro: free(): corrupted unsorted chunks: 0x094bf3f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b591)[0xb76b7591]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6cde8)[0xb76b8de8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb76bbecd]
./pro[0x8048f0d]
./pro[0x8049620]
./pro[0x80496e5]
./pro[0x8048819]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0xb7662bd6]
./pro[0x80486a1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 659889     /root/src/pro
0804b000-0804c000 r--p 00002000 08:01 659889     /root/src/pro
0804c000-0804d000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 659889     /root/src/pro
094bf000-094e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7500000-b7521000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7521000-b7600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b761b000-b7638000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 655607     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7638000-b7639000 r--p 0001c000 08:01 655607     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7639000-b763a000 rw-p 0001d000 08:01 655607     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b764b000-b764c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b764c000-b779f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 659985     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
b779f000-b77a0000 ---p 00153000 08:01 659985     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
b77a0000-b77a2000 r--p 00153000 08:01 659985     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
b77a2000-b77a3000 rw-p 00155000 08:01 659985     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
b77a3000-b77a6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77b5000-b77b9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77b9000-b77ba000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b77ba000-b77d5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 655550     /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
b77d5000-b77d6000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 655550     /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
b77d6000-b77d7000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 655550     /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
bf7f3000-bf814000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

and from gdb with bt, give me this:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7fe2430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7e9f651 in raise () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#2  0xb7ea2a82 in abort () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#3  0xb7ed649d in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#4  0xb7ee0591 in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#5  0xb7ee1de8 in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#6  0xb7ee4ecd in free () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#7  0x08048f0d in cleanReadLine (line=0x804d2e8 "#####   ", file=0x804d018) at fileio.c:233
#8  0x08049620 in passOne_3 (outFileName=0x804a4d1 "./tmp/tmp", srcFileName=0x804a495 "./tmp/tmp_no") at passOne.c:81
#9  0x080496e5 in passOne (srcFileName=0x804d008 "thisIs") at passOne.c:116
#10 0x08048819 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff5e4) at main.c:34
```

Comment: In 99.9999999999% of the cases it means you have a memory corruption bug in your code.

Comment: aha,, and how could i solve it, ?

Comment: You use a debugger (and/or valgrind) to find it.

Comment: If you post a complete example that produces this someone may be able to assist.

Comment: See the explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25767858 for a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767566/corrupted-unsorted-chunks-while-calling-free

Comment: Does this answer your question? [corrupted unsorted chunks while calling free()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767566/corrupted-unsorted-chunks-while-calling-free)