# corrupted unsorted chunks while calling free()

Tags: c

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): corrupted unsorted chunks: 0x00000000007646b0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000007635a0 ***
```

I'm getting the above error. But I'm sure that I'm not using the memory after freeing. Why do I get the above error ?

Comment: Use valgrind.  It will tell you.

Answer (score 29):

All heaps, store certain kinds of meta-data inside itself. When you do a malloc or free, the heap will often perform some book-keeping functions on the heap. If it detects something totally unexpected in the meta-data, it will normally crash.

Normal heap operations are highly unlikely to cause such problems, so your program is most likely to be the cause. Since your program has access to all the memory in the process including the heap meta-data, your program could have accidentally overwritten some of the meta-data.

A likely cause is writing beyond the end of an allocated buffer. This write will most probably be allowed and is extremely likely to corrupt the heap meta-data. When this detected by the heap, your program will normally abort.

Comment: Great comment! I'd like to add that sometimes these kinds of errors don't make themselves apparent in the exact region of code were the mistake was made, but somewhere else, in an apparently unrelated region of the code. This happens a lot, for instance, when you use LAPACK subroutines for matrix multiplication like `dgemm` and you write the wrong leading orders. The result of that particular operation may be correct but later in the code allocation of an unrelated variable may fail.

Answer (score 4):

It could be that you are trying to free with a pointer that does not correctly point to dynamically alocated memory.